# Проблема при использовании функции url

Tags: python, django

В шаблоне есть строка:

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token%}
```

которая вызывает ошибку

> Reverse for
> 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'
> with arguments '()' and keyword
> arguments '{u'uidb64': '1111',
> u'token': u'111111111111111111'}' not
> found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если "0 pattern(s) tried" - значит, ничего похожегно в urls совсем нет. Подозреваю, что вместо `'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'` должен быть name соответствующего роута.

Comment: Если передавать name, та самая ошибка.

Comment: namespace-а там случайно не указано?

Comment: Нет. Если ставить имя домашней страницы {% url 'home' %} все работает. А с 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' нет. Есть соображения что нужно использовать функцию reverse_lazy, но не знаю где именно ее применить.

Comment: lazy в шаблоне использовать смысла нет - вы все равно ее сразу выполняете.

Покажите, где и как у вас `password_reset_confirm` подключается в urls

Comment: Вы оказались правы относительно пространства имен. Не там смотрел. На локалке отправляет отлично. А вот на боевом сервере письма не приходят, никак не могу понять почему.